# Facebook IOS SDK URL scheme generation

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

The Facebook IOS SDK lets you programmatically set app ID ([FBSettings setDefaultAppID:appId]) and URL scheme suffix, but we define the URL Scheme used for returning to the calling app as fb{appId} inside .plist, which means in theory the .plist URL scheme and the dynamic URL scheme may be inconsistent.

How does the SDK handle generating the proper URL scheme for the app bridge, especially if app ID is set dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it doesn't. If you pass in something that's inconsistent then it won't return to your app. You should always test your app with all FB integrations to make sure you're setting the scheme suffix correctly.

Comment: Ah ok, may have been unclear in my comment - what I mean is, if I register URL scheme fb123 in plist, and then I use `[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:fb456]` in code, won't the SDK attempt to callback to my app using the 456 scheme (`fb456://foo`)?

Comment: Yes, it would, and it won't open your app. By "it doesn't" I meant that the SDK does not do the validation right now. If you feed it bad data, then you will get bad results. :(

Comment: Hmm.. so in essence, calling `[FBSettings setDefaultAppID]` with an app ID that doesn't match the plist value breaks the callback altogether? (Is this documented somewhere?)

Comment: Yes, Facebook only knows who's calling via the App ID (especially if there's no access token), and it can only redirect to your app using fb{app_id}, which will only open your app if it's registered in the plist. We document expected use cases in our dev site. I'm not sure why anyone would set an appID that's not one they expect.